How to style size and color of matplotlib suptitle?
This should be straightforward: I want to style the matplotlib suptitle.
Documentation says that fontproperties is a dict of font properties that can be supplied as a parameter.
So:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
fdct = {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': 32}
# Generates error
fig.suptitle('A title', fontproperties=fdct)
# Works
fig.suptitle('A title', fontsize=32)

The first command generates
TypeError: FontProperties.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
But why? I would like to style suptitle with a dict of font properties, like I do for other instances of Text.

Looking at the documentation, I don't see color or fontsize keyword argument for FontProperties. I do see a size argument though, though I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.

OK, I found a way to do it.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
fdct = {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': 32}
# Works
suptitle = fig.suptitle('A title')
suptitle.set(**fdct)

This is because Python lets you pass named parameters via a dict, provided you use the "unpack" operator **. This is actually a great feature.

color is not a property of a font, it is a property of a Text (which, besides color, has a fontproperties property that is populated by suptitle with a FontProperties instance given its fontproperties dictionary argument).
suptitle returns the Text instance that it creates. You can change its color property either by using its set method with the color keyword argument, or more explicitly by its set_color method.
Similarly, FontProperties has no fontsize property, however it does have size. You can either provide it to suptitle as fontsize, or as size via the fontproperties dictionary, or by using Text.set with fontsize keyword argument, or by using Text.set_fontsize.

OK, thanks. I understand that fontproperties does not accept a font dictionary the same way as Text does. I am used to pass a "font dictionary" to style all aspects of ax.text with one parameter (ax.text(x,y,str,fontdict=dict{...})) and that's extremely convenient. Is there a way to style the returned text instance with such a dictionary, all in one step?
